# Push to new route without any further actions on the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We use an external componet which we don't control that takes in children which can be other components or
used for routing to another page. That component is called `Modulation`.

This is how we are currently calling that external `Modulation` component within our `MyComponent`.

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import { Modulation, Type } from "external-package";

const MyComponent = ({
  router,
  Modulation,
  Type,
}) => {

  // Need to call it this way, it's how we do modulation logics.
  // So if there is match on typeA, nothing is done here.
  // if there is match on typeB perform the re routing via router push
  // match happens externally when we use this Modulation component.
  const getModulation = () => {
    return (
      <Modulation>
        <Type type="typeA"/> {/* do nothing */}

        <Type type="typeB"> {/* redirect */}
          {router.push('some.url.com')}
        </Type>
      </Modulation>
    );
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getModulation();
  }, [])
  return <Fragment />;
};

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

This `MyComponent` is then called within `MainComponent`.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';
import OtherComponent1 from '../OtherComponent1';
import OtherComponent2 from '../OtherComponent2';

const MainComponent = ({
    // some props
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <MyComponent /> {/* this is the above component */}

        {/* We should only show/reach these components if router.push() didn't happen above */}
        <OtherComponent1 />
        <OtherComponent2 />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainComponent;
```

So when we match `typeB`, we do perform the rerouting correctly.

But is not clean. `OtherComponent1` and `OtherComponent2` temporarily shows up (about 2 seconds) before it reroutes to new page.

Why? Is there a way to block it, ensure that if we are performing router.push('') we do not show these other components

and just redirect cleanly?

P.S: react-router version is `3.0.0`

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using `react-router`? It exports a `withRouter` HOC in older versions but the code you've shared isn't accessing *any* of the props it injects. What is this `router` prop? What version of `react-router` is installed? `router.push('some.url.com')` also seems like an unintentional side-effect, which is anti-pattern in React.

Comment: @DrewReese react-router version is 3.0.0. That router prop is coming from withRouter. Is there a better way to reroute instead of push here to avoid the anti pattern?

Comment: Woah, v3 (!!) Yeah, it's in imperative navigation action so it should really be executed from a lifecycle method, and in this case since it is a React function component, the `useEffect` hook. Ideally there'd be some logic right there in the `MainComponent` component to do this check, run the effect, and conditionally render what it needs to, including `null` if it doesn't need to render anything. Sounds like you are working with some relatively archaic React code though, so things might get a little weird.

Comment: I also just noticed that `getModulation` is called in a `useEffect` hook and it returns JSX, but nothing is done with the return value. This is some very odd code IMO.

Comment: @DrewReese Could try upgrade the router version if an upgraded version might give me better options. But is bit of a legacy project thus nervous to be upgrading it. Calling Modulation inside useEffect is my doing. Could call it as a normal JSX. But due to that router.push (and seem like some re rendering going on), I get caught up in an infinite loop. Thus went with calling it inside useEffect.

Comment: @DrewReese It comes back to wanting to call the Modulation component and be able redirect as mentioned above. Could call it in MainComponent directly too and drop MyComponent altogether. But if I call Modulation inside useEffect for MainComponent same issue observed too. And it has added issue where I can't enter OtherComponents anymore irregardless of which type (A or B) is chosen.

Comment: Sounds like it's either live with the existing legacy code and what it's capable of, or push your business unit to allow you to upgrade and rewrite the logic with more current React and design patterns.

Comment: @DrewReese But even if I move router to latest version, what would be a better solution here? The Modulation component would remain the same though. Considering I am trying to implement this within the week. The change to  the Modulation component/approach would take months which is optimistic considering the red tape involved, if at all possible so not feasible there. :p

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do. Either live with the existing behavior since you say you can't make changes to the `Modulation` component that you are using, or present your findings your business unit that to get the behavior they want would require the time to do it right. Can you share this external package and `Modulation` code you are using to see if there's other ways to interact with it?

Comment: @DrewReese The issue actually exists without the Modulation bit. I also resorted to use window.location.replace with same outcome. Temporary incorrect display of components before redirecting. I created a simple project to show case this issue. If you just run it on localhost:3000 after npm i can see the issue. Everything relevant is inside the App.js file. https://github.com/kvaithin/react-routing-issue .

Comment: I already explained [here](/questions/73832709/push-to-new-route-without-any-further-actions-on-the-component#comment130372042_73832709) to conditionally hide the UI until you are ready to display it.